# Compile a node's catalog to JSON without a master?

Tags: puppet, puppet-3

I'm looking to improve my org's Puppet work lifecycle by comparing differences for actual node catalogs. We came across [this project](https://github.com/acidprime/puppet-catalog-diff) which compiles catalogs for nodes and creates a diff for them, but it seems to require an online master.

I need to be able to do what this tool does, albeit without a master - I'd just like to compile a deterministic JSON or YAML blob which describes all of the resources that would be managed by Puppet for a given node and given a set of facts.

Is there a way for me to do this without an online master?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to accept my answer below?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Rspec-puppet set up, there is an easy way to do this. Just add a `File.write` statement inside one of your it blocks:

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'myclass' do
  it {
    File.write(
      'myclass.json',
      PSON.pretty_generate(catalogue)
    )
    #is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps
  }
end
```

I have more information in a blog post on this [here](https://alexharv074.github.io/2016/03/16/dumping-the-catalog-in-rspec-puppet.html).

If you can't use Rspec-puppet to do it (recommended), have a look at another blog post I wrote, [Compiling a puppet catalog – on a laptop](https://alexharv074.github.io/2015/12/31/compiling-a-puppet-catalog-on-a-laptop.html).

Comment: Is this in the documentation for `rspec-puppet`? This is the first I am seeing of this trick. Also `catalog-diff`: RIPienaar is the man. That tool has interesting implications when combined with `puppet-catalog-test` and the above. I think I may need to explore something along those lines.

Comment: I don't think it's documented, other than in the code and in my post.  I figured it out using `pry`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for it for a long time.
In the end, Vagrant in combination with Puppet brought me the solution.

The only thing you need is to install puppet.
First you have to set the Facts. After that you can compile your catalog.

```
FACTER_server_role='webstack' \
... \
FACTER_hostname='hostname' \
FACTER_fqdn='hostnamne.fqdn' \
puppet catalog compile hostnamne.fqdn \
--modulepath "./modules" \
--hiera_config "./hiera.yaml" \
--environmentpath ./environments/ \
--environment production
```

If you want to get a clean json file, pipe the output in `sed` and send the output to a file.

```
 | sed -n '1!p' > $file
```